# Как работать с register_next_step_handler

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Надо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "пополнить баланс" пользователю выходило сообщение на какую сумму он хочет пополнить и после его ввода выводилась снова клавиатура.

Вот часть кода

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def any_msg(message):
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        callback_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Выберите услугу", callback_data="1")
        callback_button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пополнить баланс", callback_data="balans")
        callback_button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Выберите направление доставки", callback_data="1.2")
        callback_button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Связь с оператором", callback_data="1.3")
        keyboard.add(callback_button, callback_button1, callback_button2, callback_button3)
        bot.reply_to(message,
                     " Привет, " + message.from_user.first_name + " \nВаш баланс:<b>0 руб</b>", parse_mode='HTML')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Грузоперевозки по всей росии, услуги грузчиков,заказ спец\n техники",reply_markup=keyboard)         
    
    
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "1":
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            a = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Грузоперевозки ", callback_data="2")
            b = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Заказ спец техники ", callback_data="2.1")
            c = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Услуги грузчиков ", callback_data="2.2")
            keyboard.add(a, b, c)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                      text="Это официальный бот", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного поправил ваш код

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def any_msg(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Выберите услугу", callback_data="choise_service"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пополнить баланс", callback_data="replenish_balans"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Выберите направление доставки", callback_data="1.2"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Связь с оператором", callback_data="1.3")
    )
    bot.reply_to(message, f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}\nВаш баланс:<b>0 руб</b>", parse_mode='HTML')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Грузоперевозки по всей росии, услуги грузчиков,заказ спец\n техники",
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "replenish_balans")
def replenish_balans(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Введите сумму пополнения")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, take_money)


def take_money(message: types.Message):
    # проверка, является ли введенный юзером текст числом (только int)
    if message.text.isdigit():
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Выберите услугу", callback_data="choise_service"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пополнить баланс", callback_data="replenish_balans"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Выберите направление доставки", callback_data="1.2"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Связь с оператором", callback_data="1.3")
        )
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         f"Счет пополнен на {message.text}",
                         reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        # в случае если не число заствляем ввести еще раз и так до победного конца
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Некоректный ввод\nВведите сумму пополнения еще раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, take_money)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "choise_service")
def choise_service(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Грузоперевозки ", callback_data="2"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Заказ спец техники ", callback_data="2.1"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Услуги грузчиков ", callback_data="2.2")
    )
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                          message_id=call.message.message_id,
                          text="Это официальный бот",
                          reply_markup=markup)
```